# Rspec: undefined method `StandardError' for EmeraldComponent:Module

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

In my gem I have the following module:

```
module EmeraldComponent

  def self.create(full_name)
    raise StandardError('Base directory for components is missing.') if base_directory_missing?
    raise StandardError('An Emerald Component must have a name.') if full_name.empty?
    raise StandardError('An Emerald Component must have a namespace.') if simple_name?(full_name)
    write_component(full_name)
    true
  end

  def self.write_component(full_name)
    ## To be implemented
  end

  def self.simple_name?(full_name)
    vet = full_name.split('.')
    vet.length == 1
  end

  def self.base_directory_missing?
    not (File.exist?(EmeraldComponent::BASE_DIRECTORY) && File.directory?(EmeraldComponent::BASE_DIRECTORY))
  end

end
```

And among my Rspec tests for this module I have these:

```
context 'create' do

  it 'raises an error if the base directory for components is missing' do
    expect {
      EmeraldComponent.create('test.component.Name')
    }.to raise_error(StandardError)
  end

  it 'raises an error if it receives an empty string as component name' do
    expect {
      EmeraldComponent.create('')
    }.to raise_error(StandardError)
  end

  it 'raises an error if it receives a non-namespaced component name' do
    expect {
      EmeraldComponent.create('test')
    }.to raise_error(StandardError)
  end

  it 'returns true if it receives a non-empty and namespaced component name' do
    expect(EmeraldComponent.create('test.component.Name')).to be true
  end
```

It happens that when I run the test all of them are passing, except for the first. This gives me the following error.

```
1) EmeraldComponent Methods create returns true if it receives a non-empty and namespaced component name
Failure/Error: raise StandardError('Base directory for components is missing.') if base_directory_missing?

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `StandardError' for EmeraldComponent:Module
 # ./lib/EmeraldComponent.rb:10:in `create'
 # ./spec/EmeraldComponent_spec.rb:48:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

As you may see, it is saying that `StandardError` is undefined for EmeraldComponent:Module.

But `StandardError` does not belong to EmeraldComponent:Module!

And besides, **this same `StandardError` is working fine for the other tests!**.

I've been fighting this error for a while and then decided to post here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be doing `StandardError.new` in place or `StandardError` in your `create` method

```
 def self.create(full_name)
    raise StandardError.new('Base directory for components is missing.') if base_directory_missing?
    raise StandardError.new('An Emerald Component must have a name.') if full_name.empty?
    raise StandardError.new('An Emerald Component must have a namespace.') if simple_name?(full_name)
    write_component(full_name)
    true
  end
```

Comment: Instead of raising `StandardError.new()` the recommended approach is to `raise StandardError, "message"`. See https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#exception-class-messages

Answer (score 1):

@victorCui is correct.

Instead of raising `StandardError.new()`, the recommended approach is to write:

```rb
raise StandardError, "message"
```

See https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#exception-class-messages